# Why is Marshmallow creating extra queries when SQLAlchemy mapping is eager

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy with Flask-Marshmallow and I'm seeing Marshmallow behavior that I don't understand.

I have a simple many-to-one SQLAlchemy which works just fine. The one side of the relationship is fetched via LEFT OUTER JOIN. My mapping looks like:

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('children.id'))
    child = db.relationship('Child', backref='parents', lazy='joined')


class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'children'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

So far so good everything works great and loads as I expect.

But then when I query and serialize with Marshmallow a SELECT is performed to get the child of every parent, despite the fact that the child is already loaded.

```
def get_parents():
    # use Flask's paginate() method
    parents = Parent.query.paginate(1, 20, False)

    # so far so good...LEFT OUTER JOIN is done...

    # BOOM below!
    return parent_paged_list_schema.dump(parents).data
```

Why doesn't the serialization process of Marshmallow just use the children already in memory?

I'm surely doing something wrong.

For reference here are what my Marshmallow schemas look like:

```
class ParentSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    child = fields.Nested(ChildSchema())

    class Meta:
        model = Parent

class ChildSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    id = fields.Integer()

    class Meta:
        model = Child

class PagedListSchema(Schema):
    # ...snip...
    pages = fields.Integer(dump_to='numPages', dump_only=True)
    per_page = fields.Integer(dump_to='perPage', dump_only=True)
    total = fields.Integer(dump_to='totalItems', dump_only=True)

class ParentPagedListSchema(PagedListSchema):
    items = fields.Nested(ParentSchema, many=True, dump_only=True)

parent_paged_list_schema = ParentPagedListSchema()
```

Comment: Do you experience the same results with `Parent.query.options(db.joinedload(Parent.child)).paginate(1, 20, False)`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I guess I could try, but I ended up working around this by putting `exclude = ('parents',)` in the `class Meta` section of the `ChildSchema`. It'd be unfortunate if I had to change perfectly fine SQLAlchemy mappings just for the sake of Marshmallow. Wish I understood this better! :-)